# Questions on achamanam and Sankalpa

Tags: shiva-purana, nama-japa

I have recently started performing Shiva nama japa and wondering if I can do a short version or achamanam by reciting Keshava, naraayana, madhava and finally govinda and not recite the rest of the 20 names. Also can I skip the sankalpa and just do viniyoga in lieu of Sankalpa? Of course I will be doing the nyasas after viniyoga though.

Comment: Some people opine that for Nitya Puja Sankalpa can be omitted. Also Achamana without Anga Sparsha (chanting various names) is also done. It's upto the individual and how he was taught the process by the Guru.